# VSTS - deploy multiple web applications

Tags: azure-devops, release-management, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am using VSTS to build a Solution containing multiple Web Applications. The web applications are being zipped up and exist in the deploy folder and I can use the **Deploy Website** task to deploy a website by specifying the Package or Folder like this:

```
$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\**\*Website.zip
```

The task deploys a single website, however I would like to deploy all the zipped websites, and any others that get added in the future without modifying the release process. Reducing the pattern restraints to match multiple websites doesn't work with the Deploy Website task. Is there task that supports the functionality of deploying multiple websites and if not what is the most idiomatic way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Do you solve this issue?

Comment: @chen-MSFT I solved this issue by having a task group with multiple IIS Web App Deploy steps. It works and is easy to understand but I'd prefer a more convention over configuration approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by having a task group with multiple IIS Web App Deploy steps, taking a convention over configuration based approach. The approach is easily understandable for anyone maintaining the deployment pipeline but for a more configuration based approach having a custom script as mentioned in Daniel Mann's answer is more suitable.

Comment: How do you get past the fact that IIS Web App Deploy wants a "Website name", but it is linked to the containing deployment process, which in effect forces the same website name for all instances of IIS Web App Deploy? Is there a way to break the variable link?

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own script to enumerate the files and publish them.

My recommendation, though, is to have your build publish multiple sets of artifacts, and then have a separate pipeline for each website. This makes it possible to deploy only a single thing at a time, making it easier to do patches and support other scenarios where doing everything at once is undesirable.